# .NET - Check if an image can be deleted or is writable after using it to perform .net image scaling

Tags: .net, vb.net, image, resize, gdi+

I've got an app where the user uploads an image and the app resizes the image three different ways based on different variables.  They all use the same image.  I can't check to see if it's done using the image so I wondered if there was a way to check to see if the file is writable.  A small loop that exits once it becomes writable (or "deleteable").  Working out of VB.NET.  Thanks!

Comment: So you want to know when it is done resizing them?

Comment: Right, when it's done resizing and can be deleted or moved.  I'm using it for other file functions as well, it would be nice to have a sure fire way to tell if it's writable.

Comment: It should be writable right away.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [the free image resizing.net library](http://imageresizing.net)? It properly closes file handles and avoids the [28 GDI bugs](http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/) that most other solutions (and all the sample code you find on the internet) have. It also supports dynamic image resizing with correctly threaded disk caching, which would probably let you skip your issue altogether.

It's been supported and maintained since 2007, and uses all the best techniques for performance and reliability. It has a 1-line API, and is very easy to use.